# How to insert a menu into android activity

Tags: android

I have an Android Application. In one Activity I want to display a menu but it not showing.

This is a method in my Activity:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_crea_ordine, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

This method return true.

This is my menu "menu_crea_ordine.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!---->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_delete"
        android:title="@string/delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
        />
    <!---->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_generateorder"
        android:title="@string/send_order_mail"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_email"
        />

    <!---->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_save"
        android:title="@string/save"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_save"
        />

    <!---->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_generatepdf"
        android:title="@string/pdf"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_pdf"
        />
</menu>
```

If I try to start my application, I can't see the menu.

This is the menu that i show, if I open menu_crea_ordine.xml

[image]

If I try tu start my activity this is the screen:

[image]

> EDIT
>   This is my xml of activity

crea_ordine.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#AAB0FF"
    android:orientation="vertical">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelCodiceEAN"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Codice EAN" />


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editCodiceBarre"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberSigned|text"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_edit_text"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editCodiceBarre"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="onScan"
            android:src="@drawable/barcode"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!---->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelDescrizione"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editDescrizione"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editDescrizione"
        android:text="Descrizione" />

    <!---->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editDescrizione"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_edit_text">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButton02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="checkArticolo"
            android:src="@drawable/search"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewDemo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ImageButton02"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my xml of menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <!--  android:icon="@drawable/home" -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"

          android:title="@string/action_search"
           />
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          />
</menu>
```

Comment: Are there any Exceptions in your error log?

Comment: your menu xml file name should be `menu_crea_ordine.xml`

Comment: Can you add a screen shot?

Comment: onCreateOptionsMenu is a boolean, so it returns true or false, Try `return true;`

Comment: Post your complete activity .

Comment: I have edit my original question

Comment: how did you implemented your toolbar ?

Comment: you are using fragment or activity?

Comment: @Kinjal, I use activity

Comment: ok have you tried my below answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Your **contact_menu.xml** file look like this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_contact"
        android:icon="@mipmap/contacts"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="" />

</menu>
```

Comment: The code not works. I can't see a menu button in front of tab application. I can see the menu only if I push the physical button of my smartphone

Comment: so it is problem of toolbar or margin or something else in your project because this code is working at my device.

Comment: How can I fixed that strange problem?

Comment: I don't have a toolbar. Where I can find it?

Comment: if I try to start my application on my Tablet 10'' with Android 4.0.3 I can see correctly a three point at right of toolbar. If I try to start my app on my smartphone with Android 5.0.1 I can't see the menu in toolbar.

Comment: give me activity xml file

Comment: I have just edit my question and I have added my xml file of acitivty

Comment: you have use actionbar or toolbar?

Comment: Action bar I think